# Setting defaults in a Ruby options hash

Tags: ruby

I have a specific method that I like because it lets me decide whether or not I want to use the default. If I want anything different I enter in `:option => value` otherwise I get the default. Here's a concrete example that works, but is a little ugly.

How can I accomplish the same thing in a more elegant manner?

```
def connect_to_oracle opts = {}
  host_name = opts[:host_name]
  host_name ||= 'a_default_host_name'
  db_name = opts[:db_name]
  db_name ||= 'a_default_db_name'
  userid = opts[:userid]
  userid ||= 'a_default_userid'
  password = opts[:password]
  password ||= 'a_default_password'
  url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:#{userid}/#{password}@#{host_name}:1521:#{db_name}"
  $db = Sequel.connect(url)
end
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't need the `||=` you can use `||`:

```
def connect_to_oracle( opts = {} )
  host_name = opts[:host_name] ||'a_default_host_name'
  db_name = opts[:db_name] || 'a_default_db_name'
  userid = opts[:userid] || 'a_default_userid'
  password = opts[:password] ||'a_default_password'

  url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:#{userid}/#{password}@#{host_name}:1521:#{db_name}"
  $db = Sequel.connect(url)
end
```

Another approach is `Hash.merge`:

```
DEFAULT = {
  host_name: 'a_default_host_name',
  db_name:  'a_default_db_name',
  userid: 'a_default_userid',
  password: 'a_default_password',
}

def connect_to_oracle( opts = {} )
  opts = DEFAULT.merge(opts)

  host_name = opts[:host_name]
  db_name = opts[:db_name]
  userid = opts[:userid]
  password = opts[:password]

  url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:#{userid}/#{password}@#{host_name}:1521:#{db_name}"
  $db = Sequel.connect(url)
end
```

or:

```
DEFAULT = {
  host_name: 'a_default_host_name',
  db_name:  'a_default_db_name',
  userid: 'a_default_userid',
  password: 'a_default_password',
}

def connect_to_oracle( interface_opts = {} )
  opts = DEFAULT.merge(interface_opts )

  url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:%s/%s@%s:1521:%s" % [
    opts[:userid],
    opts[:password],
    opts[:host_name],
    opts[:db_name],
    ]
  $db = Sequel.connect(url)
end
connect_to_oracle()
connect_to_oracle(:host_name => :xxxxxxxx)
```

I prefer the version with `merge`. So I get a constant with all default parameters in my documentation.

Another advantage: I can easily add checks if my interface contains correct keys.

Example:

```
DEFAULT = {
  host_name: 'a_default_host_name',
  db_name:  'a_default_db_name',
  userid: 'a_default_userid',
  password: 'a_default_password',
}

def connect_to_oracle( myopts = {} )
  (myopts.keys - DEFAULT.keys).each{|key|
    puts "Undefined key #{key.inspect}"
  }
  opts = DEFAULT.merge(myopts)

  url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:%s/%s@%s:1521:%s" % [
    opts[:userid],
    opts[:password],
    opts[:host_name],
    opts[:db_name],
    ]
  #~ $db = Sequel.connect(url)
end
connect_to_oracle(:host_nam => :xxxxxxxx)
```

My method call contains an error (forgotten 'e'), but when you call it, you get a warning `Undefined key host_nam`. This often helps to detect errors. (in a real scenario I replace the puts with a logger-warning/error).

Comment: `.dup.update` can also be expressed as `.merge`.

Comment: @WayneConrad Thanks. I already used it in the past, but it seems I forgot it again. I adapted my answer.

Comment: Be very careful with boolean hash parameters using the `key = ops[:key] || default` if you try to pass in false it will always default. One way around it would be to do something like `key = ops[:key].nil? ? true : ops[:key]` you could try to shorten this up by assuming that if they pass in that key it's going to be false rather than the default value, but then you run the risk that they pass in the same value as the default (assuming it's true) and you falsely presume it to be false. You could also invert your values so the default is false rather than true, but loose readability.

Answer (score 11):

**For newer ruby versions**

Since Ruby 2.1 keyword arguments are the best option.

```
def initialize(person:, greeting: "Hello")
end
```

Here, person is required while greeting is not. If you don't pass person, you will get an `ArgumentError: missing keyword: person`.

The semantics of calling a method with keyword arguments are identical to a hash.

```
Greeter.new(greeting: "Hey", person: "Mohamad")
```

---

**For older ruby versions**

For older versions of Ruby (pre 2.1), one can use fetch[`fetch`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).

Using `fetch` has two advantages:

1. It lets you set default values
2. It raises an error if you don't specify a default

```
def initialize(options = {})
  @greeting = options.fetch(:greeting, "Hello")
  @person = options.fetch(:person)
end
```

If you attempt to instantiate an object without passing a `:person`, Ruby will raise an error. While `:greeting` will default to *hello*.

Answer (score 8):

In raw Ruby, you can use `Hash#merge`. Since keys in the hash in argument will win, you can write that this way:

```
opts = {host_name: "a_default_host_name", db_name: "a_default_db_name"}.merge(opts)
```

If you use Rails framework, you can use the very convenient and elegant `Hash#reverse_merge!` method that edits the var itself (as the bang reminds you)

```
opts.reverse_merge!(host_name: "a_default_host_name", db_name: "a_default_db_name")
```

Note: You can use Active Support extensions (very useful little pieces of software that improves Ruby) without using all Rails framework, just load the extension you want, in this case it would be :

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/reverse_merge'
```

Source: [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#reverse-merge-and-reverse-merge-bang)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ruby 2.0 or better you can use keyword arguments to accomplish this very cleanly. In the past (pre 2.0) I have used a custom helper method to duplicate this functionality. The call to the helper would look like this:

```
opts.set_default_keys!({your: "default", values: "go here"})
```

The helper would be a relatively safe monkey patch on Hash and would only replace the unset keys with the default values and leave the existing values as they are.

For documentation on keyword arguments in Ruby >= 2.0 visit [rdoc.org - methods.rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Arguments)